# Multiple Emails From iTunesConnect For App Submissions?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Ever since iTunesConnect was updated, I have got anywhere from 2-5 emails for every action I take.  It is getting pretty annoying when I update an app and get 3 emails that it goes to review, 3 that it is processing, and another 3 that the app is ready for sale.  Is there some setting I can change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it appears that this is a glitch/bug in iTunes Connect. This seems to be a relatively common issue at the moment, and I have yet to see a workaround for it.

There's a whole thread on this exact topic on iPhoneDevSDK: [Link to thread](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/business-legal-app-store/119961-no-longer-receiving-itunes-connect-emails.html)

The amount appears to vary between receiving **no emails** to receiving **5 emails**.

I would recommend [submitting a bug report](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbugreport.apple.com%2F&ei=OzkqVJrKB8u0yAS-9IK4CQ&usg=AFQjCNEQImaugxdHTu_qSqGXMNVdBlYb_g&sig2=34H6K1j5Cmn4PtnIEsaNFA) to apple.